# How do I pass address of UInt32 to UIntPtr in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have the below code written in `C#`. I want to implement the same in VB.NET.

Can you please help, as I am not able to find the way to pass address of `UInt32` in VB.NET

```
UInt32 RawEncLen= 0;

[DllImport("LicCryptDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "DecryptFileEp", ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern unsafe bool DecryptFileEp(char[] BLOFile, byte[] RawEncCert, UInt32* RawEncLen);

If (DecryptFileEp(BLOFile, RawEncCert, &RawEncLen)) 
{
Console.WriteLine("Data Decrypted")
}
```

I want something similar to this:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198281/how-do-i-get-an-intptr-pointing-to-an-integer-in-vb-net/30836801#30836801)

Comment: I don't see any `UIntPtr` anywhere... You may want to fix your title.

Comment: I want this code in VB.NET which will use UIntPtr.. The code snippet of that may be:
<DllImport("LicCryptDLL.dll", EntryPoint:="DecryptFileEp", ExactSpelling:=False, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
    Private Shared Function DecryptFileEp(BLOFile As Char(), RawEncCert As Byte(), RawEncLen As UIntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

Comment: I am finding difficulty in passing the address of RawEncLen to UIntPtr

Comment: Okay, that's not actually the equivalent of your C# code, but if your C# code cannot be expressed in VB.NET and this is the closest you can get, then fair enough.

Comment: It is a simple typo, the parameter is passed by reference.  Under the hood that's implemented as a pointer to the passed variable.  Use `ref` in C#, `ByRef` in VB.NET.  Do keep in mind that the function is very dangerous, you have to take a while guess at the size of the RawEncCert array you need to pass.  That is *usually* done by calling the function twice, first by passing *null* (Nothing) for the array and then using the returned RawEncLen to know how big the array needs to be.  Use a telephone to verify that guess.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not able to understand. Can you provide me the snippet as to how do i implement it..

Comment: "while" = "wild".  You need to know more about this function to properly use it.  Basic issue is that you cannot know the *required* size of the RawEncCert array you need to pass.  It will not be the same as the size of the BLOFile array.  Look in the manual, talk to the programmer of this function to find out.

Comment: i have been given the dll. And need to use this 'DecryptFileEp function of it. I can change the size once i am able to get into the loop. However, i am getting false whenever i try to get in. This is beacause i am not able to pass the address of RawEncLen..

Comment: I deleted my answer because I was genuinely getting upset with the discussion. I will not be able to help you with this problem, because the biggest problem is not technical in nature, it's miscommunications and lack of understanding.